# GlassFish ManagedBeanCreationException and NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb, dao, facade

I have written an EJB and a dynamic web project Eclipse on GlassFish server. I used DAO , Facade and JPA. Normally I am calling a method from my service it is giving these errors ;

```
kitapOduncVerme.xhtml]com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException

PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw  exceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.mesutemre.kitapislemleri.KitapOduncVermeBean.initList(KitapOduncVermeBean.java:47)   
at com.mesutemre.kitapislemleri.KitapOduncVermeBean.initialize(KitapOduncVermeBean.java:43)
```

My codes are below;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "oduncKitapVerBean")
@ViewScoped
public class KitapOduncVermeBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Kitaplar> entityList = new ArrayList<Kitaplar>();
private Kitaplar selectedEntity;
private Kitaplar entity;
private String kullaniciadi;

private KitaplarFacade service;

public KitapOduncVermeBean() {
    entity = new Kitaplar();
    selectedEntity = new Kitaplar();

}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize(){
    HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
    kullaniciadi = Util.getUserName();
   initList();
}

private void initList(){
     entityList = service.findAllKitaplar();
}
```

DaoImpl

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Kitaplar> findAllKitaplar(){
    return em.createNamedQuery("tumkitaplarigetir").getResultList();
}
```

Dao

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class KitaplarDAO extends KitaplarDaoImpl<Kitaplar> implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public List<Kitaplar> findAllKitaplar() {
    return super.findAllKitaplar();
}
```

FacadeImpl

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class KitaplarFacadeImpl implements KitaplarFacade,Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EJB
KitaplarDAO kitapDao;


@Override
public List<Kitaplar> findAllKitaplar() {
    return kitapDao.findAllKitaplar();
}
```

}

Facade

```
@Local
public interface KitaplarFacade {
public abstract List<Kitaplar> findAllKitaplar();
```

}

I can't see any problem in this codes? But Why am I getting that errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagedBeanCrearionException` is simply wrapping and rethrowing the `NullPointerException`, that is very easy to debug: you have a null variable at the exact line that appears in the stack trace.

In `KitapOduncVermeBean` class, you are declaring `service` property, but you are not initializing it, therefore it's null when invoked in `initList()` method. Since it's an EJB, annotate it as such and the EJB container will instantiate it automatically:

```
@EJB
private KitaplarFacade service;
```

Unrelated to the concrete problem, your code is too complicated: with EJB 3.x, in most web applications, you don't need EJBs to implement or expose interfaces.